# Haskell - persistent error while trying to query just-created table

Tags: sqlite, haskell

I'm trying to query a sqlite table using persistent, but getting a message saying the table doesn't exist, right after the message saying it was created.

```
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "Post"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"content" VARCHAR NOT NULL)
user error (SQLite3 returned ErrorError while attempting to perform prepare "SELECT \"content\" FROM \"Post\" WHERE \"id\"=?": no such table: Post)
```

This is the code I am running (it's for a `scotty` web app so there is some scotty specific stuff in here)

```
runDb $ runMigration migrateAll --to create the table
liftIO $ runDb $ insert $ Post $ decodeUtf8 $ toStrict image --to attempt to insert the data, this is what fails
```

Here are my definitions of those functions:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistUpperCase|
Post
    content Text
|]

runDb :: SqlPersist (ResourceT IO) a -> IO a
runDb query = runResourceT . withSqliteConn ":memory:" . runSqlConn $ query
```

It seems to be claiming to create the table but not actually doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the table in memory, therefore, after each run of `runDb` the data is thrown away.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Use a file to store the data (ie- change ":memory:" to "filename.sqlite3").  The data will persist from run to run also.
2. Run the code to create and populate the data in a single `runDb`.  The code will work, but the data will be lost from run to run.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that is what was happening in a :memory: database. I assumed it would persist until I killed the process.